# Using pandas and scipy regression line slope to identify growth

Tags: pandas, scipy

My goal is to be able to identify price growth in a table of records.

I know this is probably far off from what is possible with data tools, so I appreciate any help or suggestions for improvement.

The immediate trouble I'm having is that `scipy.stats.linregress` does not return if some data in the pandas rows is absent. I think some kind of masking or filling will be necessary to return the slope measure for rows where there are nulls. There is an exception thrown but it still works.

Also, am I using the best solution to find the growth? 
I've observed that if I filter for the records that have a positive slope, higher rvalue (correlation) and lower stderr (standard error) the trendline for these rows is upward and consistent.

The reason I tried quantifying the price growth with the slope and other numeric values is because if I plot the lines from all the data in an excel chart, it's overwhelming to select the lines that show consistent upward movement because there is so much noise. Can it be done in a better way?

Here is the working sample:

```
# credit  jezrael

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import stats

def calc_slope(row):
    a = scipy.stats.linregress(row, y=axisvalues)
    return pd.Series(a._asdict())

table=pd.DataFrame({'Category':['A','A','A','B','C','C','C','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','D','A','B','B'],
           'Quarter':['2016-Q1','2017-Q2','2017-Q3','2017-Q4','2017-Q2','2016-Q2','2017-Q2','2016-Q3','2016-Q4','2016-Q2','2016-Q3','2017-Q4','2016-Q1','2016-Q2','2016-Q4','2016-Q4','2017-Q2','2017-Q3'],
            'Value':[100,200,500,800,700,900,300,400,600,200,300,400,200,300,100,300,500,600]})

db=(table.groupby(['Category','Quarter']).filter(lambda group: len(group) >= 1)).groupby(['Category','Quarter'])["Value"].mean()

db=db.unstack()

axisvalues=list(range(1,len(db.columns)+1)) #used in calc_slope function

db = db.join(db.apply(calc_slope,axis=1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
#np.arange instead range
axisvalues= np.arange(1,len(db.columns)+1)

def calc_slope(row):
    #mask NaNs out
    mask = row.notnull()
    a = scipy.stats.linregress(row[mask.values], y=axisvalues[mask])
    return pd.Series(a._asdict())


db = db.join(db.apply(calc_slope,axis=1))
print (db)

print (db)
          2016-Q1  2016-Q2  2016-Q3  2016-Q4  2017-Q2  2017-Q3  2017-Q4  \
Category                                                                  
A           100.0    200.0    300.0    300.0    200.0    500.0    400.0   
B           200.0    300.0    400.0    600.0    500.0    600.0    800.0   
C             NaN    900.0      NaN      NaN    500.0      NaN      NaN   
D             NaN      NaN      NaN    100.0      NaN      NaN      NaN   

             slope  intercept    rvalue    pvalue    stderr  
Category                                                     
A         0.012895   0.315789  0.802955  0.029677  0.004281  
B         0.010057  -0.885057  0.947623  0.001172  0.001516  
C        -0.007500   8.750000 -1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  
D              NaN        NaN  0.000000       NaN       NaN
```

But for last row get `RuntimeWarning`s, because only one value in `2016-Q4`.

And for remove warnings is possible use `filterwarnings`, thank [Kdog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649291/using-pandas-and-scipy-regression-line-slope-to-identify-growth#comment82257280_47649386):

```
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: Did this: import warnings ; warnings.filterwarnings("ignore"). In your opinion should I be looking for a better way to do this? Or is this as close as i'm going to get to identifying consistent growth?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you. I add it to answer.